# ArangoDB Java-driver in web-environment: configure.init() blocks

Tags: arangodb

i have a problem to run configure.init() in my Jetty-container (run-jetty-run in Eclipse with Springframework )

After reaching configure.init() the client-service blocks without any notice or exception.
If i run the same code in a console-java program it works.

I would expect output:

```
Enter init()
OK init()
Server-Version:2.6.1
```

Does somebody has any idea or experience with it ?
Java-Driver-version is 2.5.7.

Codesnippet:

```
public void arangoVersion() {
    try {
        configure = new ArangoConfigure();

        write("Enter init()");
        configure.init();
        write("OK init()"); // never reached :(

        arangoDriver = new ArangoDriver(configure);
        write("Server-Version:" + arangoDriver.getVersion().getVersion());
    } catch (ArangoException ax) {
        write("Arango-Exception" + ax.getErrorMessage() + " , Nr. : "
                + ax.getCode());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        write("Exception" + ex.getMessage() );
    }

  }  

  public void write( String text ) {
   System.out.println( text );
   // for web: logger.debug( text );
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there different versions of httpclient.jar in your maven dependencies? The java driver uses httpclient 4.3.6 which is not compatible with older versions.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

> Are there different versions of httpclient.jar in your maven
>   dependencies? The java driver uses httpclient 4.3.6 which is not
>   compatible with older versions. –  fceller Aug 28 at 8:20

Yes, indeed there was the mentioned version conflict with httpclient. An older httpclient-version was in an included (Eclipse-)project.
So configure.init() is working now.

(I would propose to catch the no-class-found-exception explitely in the Arango-Java-Driver and to make a version-check and output for httpclient. httpclient is widely spread.)

After updating the httpclient and resolving some small incompatibilities with my application the second problem occurs:

Now the ArangoDriver ran into the void with no visible reaction in my spring-application.
A debugging-session revealed that the actions of ArangoDriver where encapsulated in Springframework-transactions due AOP-coverage for all Spring-services and throws a NoClassFound-exception for the ArangoDriver.
After moving the Arango-java-driver in the same Maven-POM-layer as the SpringTX it was running perfectly.

Thanks to all.